# Why always a variable in public class and main() method is always need to be 'final'

Tags: java

Why always variables need to be final in public class and main() method. Here is the code:

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int a;
  }
}
```

In the above code, the variable cannot be public, private or not anything except final. Could you please let me know why. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read of a such a rule? It is completely wrong.

Comment: because ....... its not , nothing like this

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found this when i was programming in Eclipse, every time i create class and main method, it asks me to give final as modifier to the variables created in them and throws error if i use any other modifiers. So i was confused why is it so.

Answer (score 3):

> Why always variables needs to be final in public class and main() method

It doesn't. It's a method-local variable, so it can't have any access modifiers, but it can be either final or non-final. It has nothing to do with the enclosing class being public or the enclosing method being `main()`. It's just because it's a method-local variable. Only *member* variables can have access modifiers.

Comment: I don't think that the person asking the question is incorrect - they are correct in saying that in their code the variable can't be public or private..

Comment: @Annie The title says 'always need to be final', and it is repeated within the question. That may or may not be what the OP meant, but it's most definitely what he said. Every other answer so far relies on the same interpretation.

Comment: @Annie - If you want to claim that EJP is incorrect, you will need to provide a more convincing argument than that.  Remember, the only proven mind-reader on SO is Jon Skeet!  Unless you can show us your qualifications in remote neural sensing ... we ain't gonna believe you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a local variable. Only instance or static variables can have access modifiers.

For example an instance variable:

```
public class A {

   private int a;

   public static void main(String args[]){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to java , Local variables are only allowed to give final access,it wont be public,private or anything. The declared variable is inside the main method,so it is local variable.you are allowed to give only final to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be `final`.

It cannot be `public` or `private` as it is a local variable inside the `main` method scope. `public` or `private` have no meaning here. They can be used for [member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) variables only.

Answer (score 0):

Variables within methods do not have their own access control, you can't expose a variable that is internal to a Java method.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not at all necessary** that all the variables has to be final in any class (not just public) class. Sometimes you may need to ensure that the value of a variable is not modified in the course of time, hence you may mark it as final.

Also making **member variables as final ensures that they are thread safe**, if being shared by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of scope. Public and private indicate the scope of a variable, which basically means who gets to see it.

Public means that anyone who has an instance of A gets to see its a variable. Private means that only methods inside of the class A get to see it.

In your case, you defined a inside of the main method, which means it gets method scope and only code inside of the main method knows about a.

Final is not scope but it means that you can't assign a new value to a once it's been assigned.

For more info, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is information about scopes in Java.

Answer (score 0):

### Refutation

Go inside the main function, declare a variable without the `final` keyword.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   int noFinalNeeded; 
}
```

Prove that the statement *"Why always variables needs to be final in public class and main() method"* is **false**.

**Disproved by counterexample**.

---

For public and private: only instance variables outside a method can be public or private. Like this:

```
public MyClass
{
   private boolean thisIsMadness;
   public int thisIsSparta;

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int cookie;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public or private is the keyword which can tell others if those variables are visible to them. They tells the variable's scope.
In a method block, there is no need to use public or private because '{}' has the ability.Braces in method has already tells others that those variables are only available between { and }. So Java let 'public' or 'private' not legal in method